# Problem stopping CORB from blocking requests

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that scrapes some values from a webpage based on some query selectors that are provided via an API call.

Relevant portion of manifest.json:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
      {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["js/jquery.min.js"]
      }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "storage",
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

js/background.js:
The idea here is that if a user has entered an atsmap value on their options page, we should perform an API call.

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(['atsmap'], function(result) {
if (result.atsmap) {
        var url = "https://myurl.com/AtsMapping.aspx?AtsCode=" +
        encodeURIComponent(result.atsmap)
        fetch(url).then(r => r.text()).then(text => { 
             console.log(text);
            response = JSON.stringify(text);
            chrome.storage.sync.set({"fieldmapping": response}, function() {
          console.log('Fieldmapping is set to ' + response);
        });

           })
}
      return true;
    });
```

This portion appears to be working properly, here is the console from the background page:
[image]

In popup.js (which is included at the bottom of popup.html), I call an inject.js script after the DOM is loaded:

```
// DOM Ready
$(() => {

  'use strict';

  chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: 'js/inject.js'}, () => {
    // We don't need to inject code everwhere
    // for example on chrome:// URIs so we just
    // catch the error and log it as a warning.
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.warn(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    }
  });

  // injected code will send an event with the parsed data
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleInjectResults);

});
```

And finally, in js/inject.js, I get the value of fieldmapping from storage and attempt to use it:

```
(function () {


  'use strict';

   let fieldmap;
   let message;
console.log("test");

chrome.storage.sync.get(['atsmap'], function(result) {
if (result.atsmap) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['fieldmapping'], function(result) {
        console.log('Value currently is ' + result.fieldmapping);
        fieldmap = JSON.parse(result.fieldmapping);
        console.log(fieldmap);
    // <key> : {              // ID of input on popup.js
    //   selector: <selector> // DOM selector of value in page
    //   value: <value>       // value to use in popup.js
    // }


    if(fieldmap.AtsMapping[4].atsMapNotes == 'John Smith (2)')  {  
    message = {
      txtLName: {
        selector: fieldmap.AtsMapping[6].lastName,
        value: null
      },
```

When I go to a demo page that I've setup for the scraping, then click my extension icon, rather than scraping the page for the form values, I get the following in the console:
[image]

I don't understand how, on inject.js line 32, I can `console.log(fieldmap);` and get what appears to be the proper response, and yet on inject.js line 39, the same fieldmap is undefined.

Any suggestions would be helpful as I'm completely lost here.

Comment: Do `console.log(typeof filemap)`. If that reports `string`, It may be that you're getting back something like `JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(originalObject))`...

Comment: It is a string. So do I need to do something like JSON.parse(JSON.parse(fieldmapping)?

Comment: Apparently. Unless you have access to the code that returns that original response to you, in which I would suggest fixing that so it doesn't double-encode.

Comment: Wow. That appears to fix it. It's such a clunky way of doing things, but after staring at this for so long, I don't even care. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you step through the code in devtools debugger and inspect the variables in its UI (not via the console) you can catch issues like these almost immediately.

Comment: Actually you don't need JSON.stringify at all since the response is already a string. Remove it, remove the old value from the storage, run again, and it should work.